# C++ Dynamic array of char arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I am trying to make dynamic array of char arrays

```
const int nameLength = 10;
int dataCount = 5;

// Initialize array of char array
char ** name;
name = new char*[dataCount];
for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++)
    name[i] = new char[nameLength];

// Prompt for names
for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) {
    char userInput[nameLength];
    cout << "Input data " << i << " :";
    cin >> userInput;
    name[i] = userInput;
}
cout << endl;

// Display data entered
for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) {
    cout << "Name" << i << " : " << name[i] << endl;
}
```

But the output is wrong:

```
Input data 0 :abcde
Input data 1 :fghij
Input data 2 :klmno
Input data 3 :pqrst
Input data 4 :uvwxy

Name0 : uvwxy
Name1 : uvwxy
Name2 : uvwxy
Name3 : uvwxy
Name4 : uvwxy
```

If I change the input part to this then it would work as expected:

```
    cin >> name[i];
```

But in my case I cannot directly enter the data to the variable like that.
Can anyone explain what's wrong with the code? I searched everywhere but it doesn't seems to help

Comment: Use `strcpy` then. Or better yet `std::vector<std::string>`. Why can't you use the last code snippet?

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` than C-style arrays of characters.  Prefer to use `std::vector` rather than dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: Actually the char array is in a class and i need a function to input the char array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just copying pointers, not strings. So in fact all of your `name[i]` will be equal to `userInput`, and remember that they are both pointers. If you want to copy the full string you should use `strcpy` for example.

Since you're copying pointers, all of them point to the same string and show whatever was your last input.

Comment: is there a way to copy it without STL?

Comment: You can do a copy by hand if you like. Something like `for(int j = 0; j < nameLength; ++j) name[i][j] = userInput[j]`.

Comment: By the way, strcpy is not necessarily in STL, it's just a C function.

Comment: strcpy works just like I what I needed. At first i think i need to change all my char arrays to string to use it. thanks!